# How to show meta value code HTML after x paragraph

Tags: php, wp-query, custom-field

I have a custom field for some posts, that has the HTML code.

I want to show this code after x paragraph in the wordpress loop.

I tried with the following code, but it doens't works.

```
function prefix_insert_after_para( $ads, $content ) {
    if ( ! is_array( $ads ) ) {
        return $content;
    }

    $closing_p = '</p>';
    $paragraphs = explode( $closing_p, $content );

    foreach ($paragraphs as $index => $paragraph) {
        if ( trim( $paragraph ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $closing_p;
        }

        $n = $index + 1;
        if ( isset( $ads[ $n ] ) ) {
            $paragraphs[$index] .= $ads[ $n ];
        }
    }

    return implode( '', $paragraphs );
}

add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post' );
function prefix_insert_post( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        $content = prefix_insert_after_para( array(
           //  The format is: '{PARAGRAPH_NUMBER}' => 'AD_CODE',
           
            '4' => '' . echo get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'namevalue', TRUE) . '' ,      
            
        ), $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

With this code seems that the problem is 'echo'. Someone can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of `echo` is sending strings to the output buffer. In your code you are concatenating the result of `4` to the result of the call to `echo`, which returns nothing. Also, `get_post_meta already` returns a string so you don't have to do the type cast. Try:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'prefix_insert_post' );
function prefix_insert_post( $content ) {
    if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        $content = prefix_insert_after_para( array(
           //  The format is: '{PARAGRAPH_NUMBER}' => 'AD_CODE',
           
            '4' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'namevalue', TRUE),      
            
        ), $content );
    }

    return $content;
}
```

Remember, `echo` will immediately send a string to the output buffer which defeats the purpose of using WordPress filters since they will be used later on which is why you return the modified value on every filter.

EDIT:

`get_the_id` only works if you are inside a `WP_Query` loop. Try:

```
 if ( is_single() && ! is_admin() ) {
        global $post;
        $content = prefix_insert_after_para( array(
           //  The format is: '{PARAGRAPH_NUMBER}' => 'AD_CODE',

            '4' => get_post_meta($post->ID, 'namevalue', TRUE),      

        ), $content );
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Himad and thanks for reply. I already tried without 'echo' with only ----- '4' => get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'namevalue', TRUE), ---- but none will be displayed...

Comment: If you change the `get_post_meta` call to any fixed string like 'hello', does it display?

Comment: Yes, if I insert any HTML code it works. With php code there are some issue.

Comment: Yes, now it works. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'd appreciate if you mark the answer as correct. Happy to help :)